# How can create index number colum to sql table after data insert?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-python

what is the SQL query for create index column for SQL table?

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-index/mysql-create-index/

Comment: What is an "index column"?  Are you referring to simply creating an index on an existing column?

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE INDEX index_name
ON table_name (column1, column2, ...);
```

example (table Name = `myTable` and column Name = `col1`):

```
CREATE INDEX indexOncol1 ON myTable (col1)
```